# how to fix for run homebrew on iterm2 with zsh

Tags: homebrew, zsh, iterm2

I have MacBook Pro 13" with macOS Sierra 10.13.2 version.
And I was having problem for run homebrew with iterm2 and zsh.
I don't understand why occurs this because if I try to execute brew with the terminal app it's works fine, but not with iterm2 app.
I was searching how to do for work and so just for post and help anyone who has this problem I'm post what I do for work.

So I run this command for show where the homebrew was installed.

```
$ brew --prefix
/usr/local
$ which brew                                                             
/usr/local/bin/brew

echo $PATH brew --prefix                                             
/Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/Users/romenigld/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/romenigld/.rvm/bin:/Users/romenigld/.fzf/bin brew --prefix
```

Comment: What error do you get when you try something like `brew list`, `brew update` or `brew install wget`?

Comment: it seems the zsh don't recognize brew. the zsh ask something like:


`zsh: correct 'brew' to '.brew' [nyae]? `

So I put n and nothing. brew wasn't run on iterm2 with zsh. but with this config on the .zshenv works good.

Comment: You aren't supposed to put an answer inside your question itself. You can add your own answer, but it's supposed to be added _as an answer_, outside the question. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) on [meta].

Answer (score 0):

iTerm2 doesn't see where Homebrew is installed. Thus, find the installation folder of Homebrew, in my case, it is `/opt/homebrew/bin`. Then add the environmental variable to `~/.zshrc` file. In my case it is

```
PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary? According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout, `.zshenv` should be unconditionally sourced during shell startup. (Also, whether `/opt/homebrew` or `/usr/local/bin` is correct is dependent on the current architecture and MacOS version).

Answer (score 0):

*The below was originally added to the question itself; it's being moved to an answer for compliance with site rules*.

---

So for work I open the .zshenv file with atom:

```
atom ~/.zshenv
```

and add this:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
PATH="$PATH:$(brew --prefix)/bin"
```

so I execute brew and work's:

```
brew
Example usage:
  brew search [TEXT|/REGEX/]
  brew (info|home|options) [FORMULA...]
  brew install FORMULA...
  brew update
  brew upgrade [FORMULA...]
  brew uninstall FORMULA...
  brew list [FORMULA...]

Troubleshooting:
  brew config
  brew doctor
  brew install -vd FORMULA

Developers:
  brew create [URL [--no-fetch]]
  brew edit [FORMULA...]
  https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook.html

Further help:
  man brew
  brew help [COMMAND]
  brew home
```

Answer (score -1):

In the iterm2->preferences->profile->command->Select 'custom shell' and enter /bin/bash
That should work

Comment: The OP explicitly is configuring `.zshenv` so they can use zsh. They shouldn't be forced to use bash (and _especially_ not the more-than-a-decade-old version of bash Apple ships in `/bin`)